# If else then constraint to linearization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

Vt, At are parameters and Qt, Bt are decision variables. All of them takes positive values.

I want to linearize this equation:

if Vt - Qt > At then Bt= Vt - Qt else Bt = 0

Can you help me?